# Implementing JWT on .net core app throws invalid payload

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement JWT Token between my .net core 2.2 API and .net core 3.1 Web-Application but having trouble after login with unprotecting the token.
In debugging-mode (local computer) it works perfectly, after publishing it to my server I instantly running into various exceptions.

First I got the exception `The key {...some GUID...} was not found in the keyring`. So I read and saw, I need to set `Load User Profile` for my application-pool to `true`. That's what I've done.

Now my exception says

```
CryptographicException: The payload was invalid.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.DecryptImpl(Byte* pbCiphertext, uint cbCiphertext, Byte* pbAdditionalAuthenticatedData, uint cbAdditionalAuthenticatedData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.Internal.CngAuthenticatedEncryptorBase.Decrypt(ArraySegment<byte> ciphertext, ArraySegment<byte> additionalAuthenticatedData)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(byte[] protectedData, bool allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, out UnprotectStatus status)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(byte[] protectedData, bool ignoreRevocationErrors, out bool requiresMigration, out bool wasRevoked)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
KlehnPhotography.Site.TokenAuthentication.JwtTokenService.UnprotectToken(string protectedText) in JwtTokenValidator.cs
KlehnPhotography.Site.Service.ServiceBase.CreateClient() in ServiceBase.cs
KlehnPhotography.Site.Service.TagService.GetTags() in TagService.cs
KlehnPhotography.Site.Controllers.PhotosController.Index() in PhotosController.cs
lambda_method(Closure , object )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
....
```

I don't know where to start since locally it works fine - so debugging doesn't help.

I guess the problem is with the website, not the API (correct me if I'm wrong), so here are my Startup.cs and my TokenAuthetication-namespace:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options =>
                        {
                            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        });

    SecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mysupersecret_secretkey!123"));

    services.AddScoped<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>();

    TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters =
        new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        };

    var serialiser = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>();
    var dataProtector = services.BuildServiceProvider()
                                .GetDataProtector(new[] {"IronSphere.Web.Site-Auth"});

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                                {
                                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme =
                                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme =
                                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                                })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
                options =>
                    {
                        options.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
                        options.TicketDataFormat = new JwtTokenValidator(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                                            tokenValidationParameters, serialiser, dataProtector);
                    });

    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    services.AddTransient(x => x.GetDataProtector(new[] {"IronSphere.Web.Site-Auth"}));

    services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddOptions<AppSettings>();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ISession), serviceProvider =>
    {
        var httpContextAccessor =
            serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
    });
    services.AddTransient(typeof(ISession), serviceProvider =>
                                            {
                                                var httpContextAccessor =
                                                    serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
                                                return httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
                                            });
    services.AddTransient<IJwtTokenService, JwtTokenService>();

    services.AddDataProtection()
        .SetApplicationName("KlehnPhotography.Site");
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSession();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ImagesPath").Value),
        RequestPath = "/images"
    });

    app.UseFileServer();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

TokenValidator.cs

```
public interface IJwtTokenService
{
    string UnprotectToken(string protectedText);
}

public class JwtTokenService : IJwtTokenService
{
    private readonly IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> _ticketSerializer;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public JwtTokenService(IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> serializer, IDataProtector protector)
    {
        _ticketSerializer = serializer;
        _dataProtector = protector;
    }

    public string UnprotectToken(string protectedText)
    {
        SecurityKey signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("mysupersecret_secretkey!123"));

        TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey =
                    true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            };

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        AuthenticationTicket authTicket =
            _ticketSerializer.Deserialize(_dataProtector.Unprotect(Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(protectedText)));

        if (authTicket.Properties == null || !authTicket.Properties.Items.Any())
            return null;

        if (!authTicket.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("jwt", out string embeddedJwt))
            throw new ArgumentException("No JWT was found in the Authentication Ticket");

        handler.ValidateToken(embeddedJwt, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validToken);

        JwtSecurityToken validJwt;

        if ((validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken) == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");

        if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            throw new ArgumentException($"Algorithm must be '{SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256}'");


        return embeddedJwt;
    }
}

public class JwtTokenValidator : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
{
    private readonly string _algorithm;
    private readonly TokenValidationParameters _validationParameters;
    private readonly IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> _ticketSerializer;
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public JwtTokenValidator(string algorithm, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
        IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket> ticketSerializer, IDataProtector dataProtector)
    {
        _algorithm = algorithm;
        _validationParameters = validationParameters;
        _ticketSerializer = ticketSerializer;
        _dataProtector = dataProtector;
    }

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText) => Unprotect(protectedText, null);

    public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText, string purpose)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        AuthenticationTicket authTicket;

        try
        {
            authTicket =
                _ticketSerializer.Deserialize(_dataProtector.Unprotect(Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(protectedText)));

            if (authTicket.Properties == null || !authTicket.Properties.Items.Any())
                return null;

            if (!authTicket.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("jwt", out string embeddedJwt))
                throw new ArgumentException("No JWT was found in the Authentication Ticket");

            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            handler.ValidateToken(embeddedJwt, this._validationParameters, out SecurityToken validToken);

            JwtSecurityToken validJwt;

            if ((validJwt = validToken as JwtSecurityToken) == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid JWT");

            if (!validJwt.Header.Alg.Equals(_algorithm, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                throw new ArgumentException($"Algorithm must be '{_algorithm}'");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return authTicket;
    }

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data) => Protect(data, null);

    public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data, string purpose)
    {
        byte[] array = _ticketSerializer.Serialize(data);
        IDataProtector dataProtector = _dataProtector;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(purpose))
            dataProtector = dataProtector.CreateProtector(purpose);

        return Base64UrlTextEncoder.Encode(dataProtector.Protect(array));
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? I also could share a GitHub repo.

**update:**

Both, API and website are running on the same server. Now I added into Startup for API:

```
services
            .AddDataProtection(options => options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "SebastianKlehn")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:KeyStore").Value))
            .SetApplicationName("KlehnPhotography.API");
```

and in Startup for Website:

```
services                
            .AddDataProtection(options => options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "SebastianKlehn")
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:KeyStore").Value))
            .SetApplicationName("KlehnPhotography.Site");
```

When I didn't set `options.ApplicationDiscriminator`, no file was generated

When I start the application, I get a file in the directory of KeyStore. Each time I remove this file and I reload the website, a new file is generated with a different GUID. After removing cookies and login I get this exception:

> CryptographicException: The key {45030352-111b-460c-8419-94b48817f170} was not found in the key ring.

So I guess, the website always searches for this (and always for the same) GUID: `45030352-111b-460c-8419-94b48817f170` it never changes even after iisreset - that file is not existent in the KeyStore-folder.

In the log file for API there's:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
      Creating key {59dc92b2-1932-43d7-bb99-99c2a16e12fb} with creation date 2019-12-25 17:33:17Z, activation date 2019-12-25 17:33:17Z, and expiration date 2020-03-24 17:33:17Z.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {59dc92b2-1932-43d7-bb99-99c2a16e12fb} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[39]
      Writing data to file 'E:\wwwroot\Keys\key-59dc92b2-1932-43d7-bb99-99c2a16e12fb.xml'.
```

In the log file for website there is nothing about DataProtection or error or anything. Just the normal things like `Now listening on...` and `Application started`

Answer (score 1):

[`CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/Cng/CbcAuthenticatedEncryptor.cs#L144) throws this particular exception on two occasions: either your input paramters are garbled or your HMAC validation failed.

It is unlikely that your setup fails the first check (it's just a sanity check as far as I can tell), so it must either be your payload has indeed changed (which I assume you already ruled out) or it's the validation cipher keys are wrong.

Looking into [`KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/KeyManagement/KeyRingBasedDataProtector.cs#L197) reveals that your payload is a combination of `{ (int)magicHeader || (Guid)keyId || (byte[])encryptorSpecificProtectedPayload }`.

after that is parsed, `keyId` controls which `IAuthenticatedEncryptor` instance we'd get from the `KeyRingProvider` - that must already be initialised with correct key material and IVs at this stage. This is where I suspect your issue is - since you're running the `Unprotect` on different machines - you don't get access to the same key store and `KeyRingProvider` makes you a new `IAuthenticatedEncryptor` (even if your key-derivation passphrase is the same, we still have IVs that are likely random - I won't claim to know how exactly keys are derived).
Running both applications on the same machine likely works because of how [key auto-discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-3.1) works by default (which it seems you're relying on) - it's either taken from Windows registry or common filesystem location (depending on your OS).

Therefore I'd suggest you to configure [shared key store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) between your servers like so:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share\directory\"));
    .SetApplicationName("KlehnPhotography.Site");
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated my question with new input under **update** - it's too much to write (and added new info, maybe it'll help you/me/us :D )